# delete from pipeline function return object

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a pipe line function like below. if I want to delete some rows from the fetched output, how should I do that.

I tried myObjectFormat.delete after the END LOOP in below code.
but it didn't work.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE myObjectFormat AS OBJECT
(
    A INT,
    B DATE,
    C VARCHAR2 (25)
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE myTableType AS TABLE OF myObjectFormat
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SB360.test_func (P_ID VARCHAR2)
    RETURN myTableType
    PIPELINED
IS
    v_obj        myObjectFormat := myObjectFormat (NULL, NULL, NULL);
    v_cur        SYS_REFCURSOR;
    QUERY_STMT   VARCHAR2 (32767);
    A            INT;
    B            DATE;
    C            VARCHAR2 (25);
BEGIN
    QUERY_STMT := 'select a,b,c from test where id=' || P_ID;

    OPEN V_CUR FOR QUERY_STMT;

    LOOP
        FETCH V_CUR INTO a, b, c;

        EXIT WHEN V_CUR%NOTFOUND;

        v_obj.A := A;
        v_obj.b := b;
        v_obj.c := c;

        PIPE ROW (v_obj);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN;
END;
/
```

Comment: Please share the code where you tried to delete it, with the error details.

Comment: Why aren't you just filtering in the query, or choosing not to pipe that row, based on whatever criteria you need; rather than trying to 'delete' after piping?

Comment: No need to use a function to delete any records. Functions are not meant for those activities.